# Why is there need to set StreamReader sr = null first ?? Does it have some default value in it or what?

Tags: c#

Why set it to null first ?

[EDIT]

there was this code about reading some file..it was like

```
StreamReader sr=null;
StreamReader sr= new StreamReader("file.txt");
```

I asked why would you set "SR" as null first BEFORE referencing the file u wanna read

Comment: You really should provide an example of what you are talking about.  Otherwise, this question is about as vague as it gets.

Comment: I am talking about StreamReader here ?

Comment: And that comment is going to help?

Comment: You state that there is a "need" to set StreamReader to null.  There is no such requirement.  What is making you think this?  Are you getting errors in your code, a colleague is telling you, etc.  We need more information if we are to assist.

Comment: have added details..hope that helps now :/

Comment: I thot it must be common practice to set that pointer to null first..so asked in a general way..sry.."sr" is a pointer right ??

Comment: ok great now its closed..I editted it ! :(

Comment: Close but what for downvote??

Comment: @user: Tim's answer below should serve you. There is no need to set a StreamReader to null before constructing it.

Comment: In situations where you have a try/catch/finally (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352879/write-list-of-objects-to-a-file#answer-22416929 ), you would put the sr.Close(); in the finally block, and in such a case you need to set sr to null or to something, else you will get an error in VisualStudio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to do that...
in fact, the code above should give you a compile error as sr is already defined.

And you should probably write it as

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
        //code here
}
```

in order to make sure it is properly disposed after usage (lookup IDisposable)

Comment: ok thnx..I thot its got some default value or something