# Write list of objects to text file

Tags: c#, list, streamwriter

I've got a class Dish like this:

```
public class Dish
{
    public Dish(int cost, string name)
    {
        Cost = cost;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the main form the user can enter the previous data.
Then I create a list of "Dish":

```
public static List<Piatto> List = new List<Piatto>();
```

I created it in a static class, so I can access it from anywhere.
As soon as an item get added to the list, I want to save it in a text file (.txt) so I tried to use this:

```
public static void SaveToTxt()
    {
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path))
        {
            foreach (var item in Data.List)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I open the text file where I saved my list, I get "WindowsFormsApplication1.Dish".

How can I save to a text file showing Cost and Name?

P.s. I would like to save the list in a text file because it's easier for me to delete a line, something that I don't know how to do in binary.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Overriding the `ToString()` method worked fine. Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: you can serialize them. check these two links :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352879/write-list-of-objects-to-a-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file

Comment: _"Overriding the ToString() method worked fine. Thank you all for the answers!"_ - you should accept the answer then

Comment: Yes, sorry! I was trying every piece of code people gave me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `item` is an object that contains several properties and you have to access them:

```
public static void SaveToTxt()
{
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path))
    {
        foreach (var item in Data.List)
        {
            tw.WriteLine(string.Format("Item: {0} - Cost: {1}", item.Name, item.Cost.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its simple, You are almost there, I think you forgot to override the [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method inside your class. By overriding the `.ToString()` method you can return the string representation of its object. You can format them as well. So you have to add this overrided `.ToString()` method to make it work. Consider the following code

```
public class Dish
{
    public Dish(int cost, string name)
    {
        Cost = cost;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() 
    {
       return String.Format("Item Name :{0} \n Item Cost : {1}", this.Name,this.Cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: @the Down-voter: please specify the reason so that I improve the post. if it's personal then need not to specify the reason, accepting it as a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using XmlSerializer to write content of your object to an XML-file.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815813/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-c

Answer (score 1):

Override the `ToString()` method in `Dish`. For example:

```
public class Dish
{
   // rest of code..


   public override string ToString() 
   {
      return Cost.ToString() + " " + Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to note that, anyway happy coding..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the attributes, so something like:

```
foreach (var item in Data.List)
{
    tw.WriteLine(item.Cost.ToString() + " " + item.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to something like this

```
public static void SaveToTxt()
{
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path))
    {
        foreach (var item in Data.List)
        {
            tw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", item.Name, item.Cost));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pitersmx looks like someone downvoted all the answers. They're not some fantastic pieces of code, but they work and solve OP's problem.

Comment: I will bump it up :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `ToString` method of your class like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name: {0}, Cost: {1}",Name,Cost);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to override ToString method in your Dish class:

```
public class Dish
{
    public Dish(int cost, string name)
    {
        Cost = cost;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}: {Cost.ToString("c")}"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to write, the quickest way without too many code changes is to override your ToString method.

```
public class Dish
{
    public Dish(int cost, string name)
    {
       Cost = cost;
       Name = name;
    }

    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString(){
        return "Name: "+Name+" cost: "+cost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When converting `Dish` instance into `String`, .Net uses `ToString()` method which default (i.e. `Object.ToString()`) implementation returns item's type name:

```
   WindowsFormsApplication1.Dish
```

you can either provide your version of `ToString`:

```
   public class Dish 
   {
     ...

       public override string ToString() 
       {
           return $"{Cost} {Name}";         
       }
   }
```

Or put the right format in the very place you write it into the file (with a little help of *Linq* - `Select`):

```
   public static void SaveToTxt() {
     // File class allows to get rid of pesky readers and writers
     File.WriteAllLines(Path, Data.List.Select(dish => $"{dish.Cost} {dish.Name}"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Steps:

1.Get the list of Item in the Candidate Class object

2.Pass the list of Candidate in the Save method

3.Write the content in the Text files**

```
    public class Candidate
    {
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public string Department{get;set;}
    }        
    public void save(List<Candidate>iolist)
    {          
     var dir = @"D:\New folder\log";
     string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "items1213.txt");
     File.WriteAllLines(path, iolist.Select(o => o.Name + " " + o.Department));    
    }
```